# Display 3 Random Cards JavaFX

Tags: java, random, javafx, display

So basically the challenge is in the title. It's pretty basic but I think I have most of it. The one problem I am having is that the place from which the pictures of the cards are coming from. i know that usually you have them coming from your computer, but I am doing it where the pics are coming from an web URL. This is what i have so far but I am getting a host of errors(InvocationTargetException, Runtime, and IndexOutOfBounds) Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
public class Exercise14_03 extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));

        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);

        ImageView view1 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(0) + ".png"));
        ImageView view2 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(1) + ".png"));
        ImageView view3 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(2) + ".png"));

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().add(view1);
        root.getChildren().add(view2);
        root.getChildren().add(view3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_03");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(EXCEPTIONS)

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at Exercise14_03.start(Exercise14_03.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
```

Comment: Can you post the precise exception messages?

Comment: Why don't you fix the indentation, etc. Then the error will be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The reason people use style guides for indentation, etc, is that it reduces the possibility for errors. If you take your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
public class Exercise14_03 extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));

        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);

        ImageView view1 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(0) + ".png"));
        ImageView view2 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(1) + ".png"));
        ImageView view3 = new ImageView(new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(2) + ".png"));

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().add(view1);
        root.getChildren().add(view2);
        root.getChildren().add(view3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_03");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and indent it correctly (most IDEs will do this for you, e.g. in Eclipse you can select everything with CTRL-A and then format it with CTRL-SHIFT-F), you get

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Exercise14_03 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));

            java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);

            ImageView view1 = new ImageView(
                    new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(0) + ".png"));
            ImageView view2 = new ImageView(
                    new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(1) + ".png"));
            ImageView view3 = new ImageView(
                    new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(2) + ".png"));

            HBox root = new HBox();

            root.getChildren().add(view1);
            root.getChildren().add(view2);
            root.getChildren().add(view3);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_03");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is obvious: almost your entire `start(...)` method is inside your `for` loop. On the first iteration of the loop, you add the first element, then try to access elements 0, 1, and 2, causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Just move the code out of the for loop:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class Exercise14_03 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            cards.add(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        }

        java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);

        ImageView view1 = new ImageView(
                new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(0) + ".png"));
        ImageView view2 = new ImageView(
                new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(1) + ".png"));
        ImageView view3 = new ImageView(
                new Image("https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/book/image/card/" + cards.get(2) + ".png"));

        HBox root = new HBox();

        root.getChildren().add(view1);
        root.getChildren().add(view2);
        root.getChildren().add(view3);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise14_03");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It is also useful to learn [how to read the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450).

Comment: Idk why I didn't see that haha, and yeah I think I'm still getting used to the copy and pasting of stackoverflow because it looks the same as what you posted on my end. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Jmpollock56 You didn't see it because it's not indented correctly, and because you didn't bother reading the error message.